# Beautiful Soup Table isn't Appearing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was practicing web scraping, and I decide to check out of the sites I use the most, [Flash Score](http://www.flashscore.com/) and quickly ran into some trouble.

My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.flashscore.com/').read())
print soup.find("div", id = "fscon")
```

However this returns:

```
<div id="fscon">
<div class="preload pvisit" id="preload"><span>Loading ...</span></div>
</div>
```

Instead of what I see in the HTML when I have seen the webpage which includes the main table with all the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular page is not the easiest case to start web-scraping since it is quite "dynamic", it involves additional requests and the javascript execution to load the page completely.

The most high-level option would be to use a real browser to load the page in, wait for the complete load and parse the HTML. Working example using [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'http://www.flashscore.com/'
driver.get(url)

# wait for the complete page load
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "preload")))

# parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("div", id = "fscon"))

driver.close()
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know you've been preparing the answer and the code that uses requests all these 19 hours after the question was posted :) Interesting case though! Thanks.

Comment: lol, contemplated it until I opened developer tools and had a look at the requests then hastily closed developer tools :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham lol, exactly the same here - I suspect they intentionally obfuscate/uglify the XHR responses to tackle web-scrapers..understandably, of course..

Comment: @alecxe Thank you, let me take some time to dive into this to make sure I understand everything before I mark it as correct